# Binary Explotation: Buffer Overflow

Tags: python, c, security, binary

I need to get call the call_me() function in order to get the flag.

flag.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "../../shared/kernels_lib.c"

typedef struct node_t {
    int x;
    char y;
    float z;
 } weird_node;

void unsafe() {
  int characters_read;
  int some_other_value = 0xFFFF;
  int* protector = (int *)malloc(sizeof(weird_node)*33);
  char buffer[24];

  printf("Give me some strings (Mind your values!):\n");
  read(0, buffer, 1000);
  characters_read = strlen(buffer);

  if (*(&protector + some_other_value) == 0xbadf00d) {
      if (characters_read > 24) {
              printf("\n\ttoo many characters read!\n");
              exit(-1);
    } else {
      call_me();
    }
  }
 }

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  unsafe();
  return 0;
}
```

e.py:

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python3

 import sys
 import os
 from pwn import *

 context.update(arch='x86_64', os='linux')

 payload = cyclic(32)
 payload += p64(0xbadf00d)
 payload += p64(0xFFFFFF)
```

I have achieved in modify the value of protector to 0xbadf00d in order to pass the first if condition, but I have no idea on how to pass the second, I have try to modify also the characters_read variable but I can success on it. Can you please help me with some hints. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you remember how strlen decides where a string ends?

Answer (score 2):

I had to add 0x00 in the payload in order to fool the strlen function

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).